# Azure portal Web Service PHP Monitoring

Tags: php, azure-web-app-service

I wrote a simple Application in HTML with a form. I submit the form into a PHP file and insert the data into a database.

I created an App Service on Azure Portal + MySQL database

It took me a while to get the git Pipeline going (So Git - Azure Portal - deploying into a Webservice)
If I submit my form, the data will go to the database just fine.

Now I wanted to extend everything with a monitoring tool. So I tried Application Insights. But unfortunately, that doesn't work. If I understand it correctly it's because of the PHP file or to be exact the Php Stackruntime on Azure.

Is it possible to the monitoring anyway somehow? I only have experience in Php and Html a little bit of Java and Javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: We use grafana as monitoring tool - might wanna have a look at it..

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed sample `PHP` App to `Azure App Service`.

> So I tried Application Insights. But unfortunately, that doesn't work.

I have checked with both `PHP` 8.0 and 8.1 runtime version. The Application Insights option is disabled for `PHP`.

[image]

Thanks @[Dmitry-Matveev](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-PHP)  for the Application Insights SDK.

> Is it possible to the monitoring anyway somehow?
> Check the below steps to `Monitor` Azure PHP App Service.

***Way 1:***

Check the `Logs` under Monitoring.

[image]

***Way 2:***

- Enable `Application logging` (File System).

[image]

- Navigate to the `Log stream` to check the `Live metrics`.
  [image]

Also, we can check the metrics section to monitor the App.

[image]